# set desired location in android

Tags: java, android, cross-platform

How to set a desired location in android and give user 10 points if within a radius

```
final Button hereButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getPoints);
hereButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){
String coordinates[] = {"40.000000", "-80.000000"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
final double radius = 480; //0.3 miles
//distance = coordinates.distance(from: userLocation)
if coordinates < radius
    {
        Total_Points += 10
    }



        }
    });
```

Comment: That is fine but how would I create the let statement for the coordinates in android is the question?

Comment: I posted my attempt...apologies in advance as I am new to android/java. I also do not know how to post the incremented points on the label widget

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming you have the same classes in your java code  :

```
int Total_Points = 0;
CLLocation desiredlocation = CLLocation(45.000000,-80.000000);
Double radius = 480; // ~0.3 miles

Double distance = desiredlocation.distance(userLocation);
if (distance < radius){
      
   Total_Points += 10;
   pointsLabel.setText("Total Points: \(Total_Points)");

    getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false;

  }


 save.setValue(Total_Points, "Total Points");
```

## but if you want android equivalent of this swift code it is something else